# Debugging in IntelliJ (Reloading changed classes)

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, intellij-idea, hotswap

I recently switched from eclipse to IntelliJ. Eclipse's debug launcher used to reload the application instantly, whenever a class was saved. IntelliJ takes more than 10 secs to reload changed classes, which might not be a lot, but it is annoying because I use it so frequently.

How to make IntelliJ reload changed classes faster?

Comment: Please provide more information about your project. I mean Web/Desktop, build system name (Maven, Gradle). For instance in web projects you can setup a hotswap to a frame deactivation hook."Run/Debug Configurations"->"Your Configuration Name"->"Server (tab)"->"On frame deactivation" set it to "Hot Swap classes". And every time, when window will be switched from Idea to other (browser for instance), changes will be reloaded immediately.

Comment: @Taras my project is Desktop , Gradle , libGDX framework

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+A find registry          
  compiler.automake.trigger.delay=500---According to ur requirement

Answer (score 14):

To reload changed classes

1. Do one of the following:

- On the main menu, choose Run | Debugging Actions | Reload Changed Classes.
- On the main menu, choose Build | Compile "class_name" to recompile an altered class during debug.

2. In the Reload Changed Classes dialog box, confirm reloading. Results are displayed in the Messages tool window.

[Refer this link for detailed explanation.](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/reloading-classes.html)

Comment: as i said i am reloading changed classes but this takes a lot of time, while eclipse takes no time at all(i tested it for the same project). What i want to know is that whether is there any other faster way to do in intellij.
thanks for your effort:)

Comment: in the new IntelliJ Idea you can find Reload Changed Classes under Run -> Debugging Actions -> Reload Changed Classes

Comment: I can't find the Reload Changed Classes dialog box. Was that removed?

Answer (score 4):

InteliJ is not recompiling the code after change in java files and rebuilding

1. Project >  Setting>Build,Execution,Deployment>Compiler>check "build project automatically"
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> find "registry", according to your requirements check the following:

   ```
   compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running
   compiler.automake.trigger.delay=500
   ```
3. Add devtool in `pom.xml`:

   ```xml
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
       <optional>true</optional>
   </dependency>
   ```
4. Build, If found any probelm while building, saying some jar in not in class path. Just delete the corrupted jar and re-build the project angain after sync with maven libb

Answer (score 1):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
2. type `rcc` (or "recompile changed classes")
3. Hit enter

next time you dont need to type, it will give the last run action