# Is it possible to setup Reload Changed Classes automatically in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, runtime

I would like to automatize this task on intelliJ (under Run menu)

[image]

I usually have to run this task when I'm changing some code while running my app in debug mode.

I don't want to rebuild / recompile the whole project as some answers suggest but only do this action, is it possible to do it automatically let's say when I save my file ?

I understand that there is a difference between rebuild / recompile and reload, stop me if I am wrong.

There are some similar questions like this one, but none of them answers my question, see:

[Debugging in IntelliJ (Reloading changed classes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32692104/debugging-in-intellij-reloading-changed-classes)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debugging in IntelliJ (Reloading changed classes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32692104/debugging-in-intellij-reloading-changed-classes)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to go to:

1. Edit => Macros => Start recording macro => ctrl + S then Run => Reload Changed Classes
2. Edit => Macros => Stop recording macro (and give it a name, let's say Save and reload)
3. File => Settings => Keymap => find your macro in this list, and bind the key you want, in my case ctrl + S

Now when I press CTRL + S to save my file it also reloads the changed classes !